# Issue importing s3 buckets using Terraform s3 module

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Facing issue importing existing resources using [s3 module](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/s3-bucket/aws/latest). I can import one bucket fine -
terraform import 'module.s3_bucket.aws_s3_bucket.this[0]' bucket-1

But then I try to import another bucket -
terraform import 'module.s3_bucket.aws_s3_bucket.this[0]' bucket-2
getting below error -

> Error: Resource already managed by Terraform

I know it is an indexing issue, but how to resolve this? I have 50+ buckets.

```
module "s3_bucket" {
  source = "terraform-aws-modules/s3-bucket/aws"
  version = "3.6.1"
  bucket = "bucket-1"
}
```

Updates -
I manage to import multiple buckets using for each like this -

```
module "s3_bucket" {
  source = "terraform-aws-modules/s3-bucket/aws"
  version = "3.6.1"

    
  for_each = local.s3_buckets

  
  bucket = each.key 
}
```

and my locals.tf -

```
locals {

  s3_buckets = {

    bucket-1 = {}
    

  }

}
```

but even after successful import, Terraform wants to create the existing buckets -

```
Plan: 2 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.
```

Update 2:
Finally able to import buckets, as below -

```
terraform import 'module.s3_bucket["bucket-1"].aws_s3_bucket.this[0]' bucket-1
terraform import 'module.s3_bucket["bucket-2"].aws_s3_bucket.this[0]' bucket-2
```

Thanks !!

Comment: Well, simple: just use another index each time.

Comment: @MarkoE, tried that - terraform import 'module.s3_bucket..aws_s3_bucket.this[1]' bucket-2, terraform plan then shows it want to replace bucket-1 with bucket-1 "Plan: 2 to add, 0 to change, 2 to destroy.

Comment: That's probably because your `count` meta-argument is set to 1. You should set it to a value which will allow importing all 50+ buckets.

Comment: How to set that count meta-argument to > 50 ? In the module count is used as conditional meta-argument @MarkoE

Comment: I don't know since you haven't added any code to the question. :)